# Как установить дружественную связь между классом и шаблоном класса?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

Как можно установить дружественную связь между обычным классом и шаблоном класса?

Допустим у нас есть шаблон класса MyArray `template <typename Type> class MyArray;`
и обычный класс ArrayEditor `class ArrayEditor;`

Каким образом я могу установить между ними дружественную связь *(friend class)*:

1. Между классом **ArrayEditor** и всеми экземплярами шаблона **MyArray**?
2. Между классом **ArrayEditor** и конкретным экземпляром (например int
       или string)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Между нешаблонным классом `NotemplateClass` и общим шаблоном класса `TemplateClass<T>`:

```
template <typename T>
class TemplateClass{};

class NotemplateClass
{
   template<typename T>
   friend class TemplateClass;
};
```

---

Между нешаблонным классом `NotemplateClass` и явной специализацией шаблонного класса `TemplateClass<int>`:

```
template <typename T>
class TemplateClass{};

template <>
class TemplateClass<int>{};

class NotemplateClass
{
   friend class TemplateClass<int>;
};
```

Comment: Хм, так просто! Спасибо

Comment: @Nexeon Да, так все и есть, не за что :)